# How to use managed identity in order to connect to sharepoint through Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-synapse

I would like to use synapse to get data from sharepoint.

I would like to connect to sharepoint via synapse with system managed identity.

I tried to add a system managed identity in synapse but didn't see it.

How can I do this ? Not sure if I have to define manage identity in both (synapse and sharepoint).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, In Synapse or in ADF, connecting to SharePoint is only possible using **Service principal**.

You can see that there is no option of adding Managed identity in the SharePoint linked service.

[image]

You can raise your idea as a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).

If you want to use only Managed identity, then you can try services like logic apps. Go through this [tutorial](https://learningbydoing.cloud/blog/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-using-managed-identity-with-granular-access-permissions/) by @[LearningByDoing.cloud](https://learningbydoing.cloud/).